# Limit of decreasing functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of positive, integrable, decreasing functions. Assume Lebesgue measure.

Suppose $\int f_n$ goes to $0$. Show $f_n$ goes to $0$ almost everywhere.

This is a Qualifying exam question from a measure theory exam. It seems so obvious to me, yet...I don't know what to do.

Comment: Wouldn't $(f_n)$ have to tend to $0$ *everywhere*? (Assuming your space is $(0,1)$, e.g.)

Comment: What is the space? If it is $\mathbb R$, and $f\ge 0$, decreasing and $\int f<\infty$, then $f=0$ a.e.

Comment: I'm refinding the question.

Comment: Space is the real line in the original problem.

Comment: If the space is the real line, this is trivially true, per Yiorgos' comment. (Unless I'm missing something.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi(x) = \limsup_n f_n(x)$. Suppose $\phi(x) >0$ for $x \in A$ where $A$ has positive measure. Then for any $ x \in A$, we can find a subsequence $n_k$ such that $f_{n_k}(x) \ge {1 \over 2} \phi(x)$.

Choose any $x_0 \in A$ so that $A'=A \cap (-\infty, x_0]$ has positive measure. Let $n_k$ be the subsequence described previously.

Then for any $x\in A'$, we have $f_{n_k}(x) \ge f_{n_k}(x_0)$, and $\int f_{n_k} \ge \int_{A'} f_{n_k} \ge {1 \over 2} \phi(x_0) m A'$, which contradicts $\int f_n \to 0$. Hence $\phi(x) = 0$ for ae. $x$.

Comment: I suppose once you see that liminf is $0$, you can use a simple argument like this to get the limsup. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: It seems you can simplify this. If $\lim_n f_n(x)\ne 0$, then choose $\alpha>0$ and $(f_{n_k})$ with $f_{n_k}(x)>\alpha$. It  follows that if $x$ is an interior point of the (unspecified) interval of integration, then $\int f_{n_k}\ge\alpha\cdot \delta$ for some $\delta>0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: True; my proof could be tidied up a bit...